# Design patterns for multiple DB scenario

Tags: design-patterns

Our .NET application needs to connect to 2 different SQL databases. Some queries will be routed to the 1st DB and some to the second one. Are there any specific design patterns to achieve this. Is there any DataAdapter that can switch at runtime from one DB to another.

Comment: You could set up linked tables from one DB to the other, then you would only have to run calculations on only one view in one DB.

Comment: For an expert, you dont accept a lot - go fix!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encapsulate each database behind a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - when it comes to databases we often tend to call them [Repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). You can now encapsulate both implementations behind a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) that routes the request.

Imagine that we have an IRepository interface. You can route them like this:

```
public class RoutingRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository repository1;
    private readonly IRepository repository2;

    public RoutingRepository(IRepository repository1, IRepository repository2)
    {
        if (repository1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository1");
        }
        if (repository2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository2");
        }

        this.repository1 = repository1;
        this.repository2 = repository2;
    }

    public SomeEntity SelectEntity(int id)
    {
        if (this.UseRepository1())
        {
            return this.repository1.SelectEntity(id);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.repository2.SelectEntity(id);
        }
    }

    // more IRepository members can go here...

    private bool UseRepository1()
    {
        // implement routing logic here...
    }
}
```

Clients will only see the IRepository interface, so according to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), they will never know the difference.

Comment: Dunno why but this post made me think of http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/07/DependencyInjectionIsLooseCoupling.aspx which is worth a read even if slightly tangential to this question.